# Array to string conversion exception with PHP 7

Tags: php

I was working with old legacy code and checked if it's running with PHP7. I got an exception (`Array to string conversion`) with following code:

```
json_decode($json_string)
  ->$array['id']
  ->foo
```

What helped was to use the curly brackets:

```
json_decode($json_string)
  ->{$array['id']}
  ->foo
```

My question is, was that already wrong PHP5 and if not, which change is the reason for that? Could not find anything because did not know for what to search... One idea I had is that the new introduced AST produces this behavior?

Comment: https://github.com/tpunt/PHP7-Reference#uniform-variable-syntax

Comment: @Steve: I don't get it. Why did you post the correct answer as a comment? Please answer the question so I can mark it as solution otherwise I'll do it on my own.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon, and i didn't feel like extracting the relevant parts when the link explains it so concisely. For completeness sake, if you want so self answer, go right ahead, but make sure you include the relevant parts in the actual answer, not just the link

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right. From what I know in PHP5 that works without any exception, but PHP 7 wants to be just a little bit more strict, because cases like this can cause a lot big problems after when not used correctly.

Comment: See comment by Steve below my question.